# Protocol Oriented Programming and Class Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, protocols

I am trying to implement protocol oriented class watching tutorials from on of the popular tutorial sites. I got everything correct so far but for some reason one of the properties is not being updated while the others are updated. 
Here is the code :

```
protocol Paintable  : class {
    var primaryBodyColor : String{get set}
    var secondaryBodyColor : [String]? {get set}

    func paint(newPrimaryColor : String, newSecondaryColor : [String]?)
}


extension Paintable   {
    var primaryBodyColor : String {
        get {
            return "Black"
        }
        set {
        }
    }
}

protocol Wheeled {
    var numberOfWheels : Int {get set}
}


extension Wheeled {
    var numberOfWheels : Int {
        get {
            return 4
        }

        set {
        }
    }
}
protocol EngineSize {
    var engineSizeCC : Int {get set}
}

extension EngineSize {
    var engineSizeCC : Int {
        return 2300
    }
}




class Honda : Transport, Paintable, Wheeled, EngineSize {
    var secondaryBodyColor : [String]?
    var engineSizeCC : Int
    //We can also override default initializer of protocol, here we are going to instantiate with our initializer
    init(engineSizeCC : Int){
        self.engineSizeCC = engineSizeCC
    }

    func paint(newPrimaryColor: String, newSecondaryColor: [String]?) {
        primaryBodyColor = newPrimaryColor
        secondaryBodyColor = newSecondaryColor
    }
}

var civic = Honda(engineSizeCC: 400)
civic.primaryBodyColor
civic.passengerCapacity
civic.numberOfWheels
civic.engineSizeCC

civic.paint("blue", newSecondaryColor: ["Red","Purple"])
civic.primaryBodyColor -> "Black"
civic.secondaryColor -> ["Red"], ["Purple"]
```

The problem I am having is the primaryBodyColor stays "Black" even though I called the "paint" function to set the primary color as "Blue" and secondary color.

I am new to protocol oreinted programming so I will appreciate help on resolving this issue.

Comment: You need to implement `primaryBodyColor` in `Honda` because the default implementation in `Paintable` is not correct.

Comment: @Sulthan I don't follow. The paint method is working in secondaryBodyColors  but not in primaryBodyColor. I would appreciate if you show me how to fix the problem in *paint method*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensions cannot store properties, which is perhaps why you don't have any code in the setter of `primaryBodyColor`.  The implementation of `primaryBodyColor` needs to be in a struct/class, just as you've done with `seondaryBodyColor`. So if just before that line within the Honda class you include the following line, your code will work as expected...

```
var primaryBodyColor = "black"
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that a little later and yes that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Like it's been said in the comments, your implementation of the `primaryBodyColor` always return black and doesn't allow to be set.

By default, properties in Swift have a `get` and `set` method, there's no need to add `{get set}` after each one of them.

If you want to add a default value, you can do it like this:

```
var primaryBodyColor = "Black"
```

You don't even need to declare it as String because the compiler will realize that `"Black"` is a string and type it correctly.

Comment: is it possible to change the default value using the *paint* function instead of intializing it.

Comment: I also think property in Protocol must have explicit getter and setter.

Comment: I didn't know that, I'll investigate more.